# Webpack dev server doesn't building app before start

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have following dev-server configuration

```
devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    watchOptions: {
        aggregateTimeout: 300,
        poll: 1000,
    },
    compress: true,
    inline: true,
    contentBase: BUILD_PATH,
    historyApiFallback: true,
}
```

Where

```
BUILD_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, '../build/webapp')
```

The problem is that `../build/webapp` folder is empty when dev-server started.
As result application loading fine (index.html, bundle.js) but cannot load any fonts or other resources which should be located in assets subfolder.

And if i run just webpack - everything appears in that folder. After `webpack` i can start dev-server and everything good.

Dev-server logs:

```
    Project is running at http://0.0.0.0:3000/
    webpack output is served from /
    Content not from webpack is served from D:\Development\Projects\myproject\build\webapp
    404s will fallback to /index.html 
10% building modules 5/8 modules 3 active
     ...oject\webapp\node_modules\url\url.js(node:5560) 
 63% building modules 746/839 modules 93 active ...node_modules\lodash-es\_freeGlob
    al.js
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The webpack devserver mode build and handle result in memory and does not save to disk. It save them to disk in build mode (not in devserver mode).

Typical solution is do runing webpack in watch mode in parallel to devserver:

```js
webpack -w
```

Also there [write-file-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/write-file-webpack-plugin) for devserver is used some people:

Comment: How can i force dev-server to include fonts that are loaded by webpack 'url-loader' ? (they are seperate woff files in assets folder if i running webpack)

Comment: I can see them in dev-server logs `     /assets/fonts/source-sans-pro-v9-latin-700italic.woff2    13.7 kB          [emitted]
     /assets/fonts/inconsolata-v15-latin_latin-ext-700.woff    35.9 kB          [emitted]...
`
but cant access them via browser. 404 error

Comment: You can access them from browser from webpack dev server url:port.